# logging - how to ignore imported module logs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, logging

How to ignore log entries from imported modules (not written by me)?

The setup:

```
import logging    
import <someOtherModule>

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)    

class myClass: 
   ...
   def some_method(self):
       logging.info('calling module')
       someOtherModule.function()
       logging.info('stuff happened')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = myClass().some_method()
```

The Log:

```
INFO:root:calling module
INFO:<someOtherModule>.<some dependency> <random dependency message here>
INFO:root:stuff happened
```

How can I get rid of that middle message?

I was not able to find an answer after looking at the logging documentation or by googling.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358512/imported-module-adding-unwanted-logging-how-can-it-be-suppressed) answer but the workaround does not seem to work for me.

For the curious ones the actual log entry is:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): <address here>
```

Comment: Top answers in linked questions are more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have different levels for logging, like:

```
      'debug': logging.DEBUG,
      'info': logging.INFO,
      'warning': logging.WARNING,
      'error': logging.ERROR,
      'critical': logging.CRITICAL
```

So, if you don't want to see `INFO` level, just raise the level, like:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)
```

Don't forget to change level of log for your wanted information to `CRITICAL`.

OR:

Try this:

```
...
logger = logging.getLogger()
...
logger.disabled = True
someOtherModule.function()
logger.disabled = False
...
```

Hope your issue solves. :)

Comment: I ended up raising the logging level. Is not as clean as I would like but it would work. thanks!

Answer (score 9):

One work around(which I admit not a pretty one though), is to use the [logging.disable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.disable) method to disable the INFO logs at the time of calling the dependency methods.

```
class myClass: 
    ...
   def some_method(self):
       logging.info('calling module')
       logging.disable(logging.INFO)
       someOtherModule.function()
       logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
       logging.info('stuff happened')
```

One advantage, I think, this gives you is that if there are any errorwarning/critical failure log messages are to be reported by the dependency module, this will allow only them. You can set the disable attribute to logging.WARNING to report only error or failure messages.

Comment: This is a much neater solution than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the logging level for a given module with:

```
logging.getLogger("someOtherModule").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```